# NSTimers and triggers in Obj-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to start an NSTimer at viewdidload and then execute a few void functions at specific intervals. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your basic pattern:

MyViewController.h:

```
...
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    ...
    NSTimer* timer;
    ...
}
...
```

MyViewController.m:

```
...
static const NSTimeInterval TIMER_INTERVAL = 1.0;
...
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self stopTimer];
    ...
    [super dealloc];
}
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [self startTimer];
    ...
}
...
- (void)startTimer
{
    [self stopTimer];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIMER_INTERVAL
                                             target:self
                                             selector:@selector(timerCallback)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
    [timer retain];
}
...
- (void)stopTimer
{
    if (timer)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        [timer release];
        timer = nil;
    }
}
...
- (void)timerCallback
{
    someFunction();
    [self someMethod];
}
```

Comment: [self stopTimer]; <- About this line in dealloc, the timer will retain the receiver, so if you are in dealloc, the timer has already stopped. Otherwise you had to break the memory management rule of ObjC.